# Number of elements in a channel

Tags: go

Using a buffered channel, how do measure how many elements are in the channel? For example, I'm creating and sending on a channel like this:

```
send_ch := make(chan []byte, 100)
// code
send_ch <- msg
```

I want to measure how many **msgs** are in the channel **send_ch**.

I'm aware that due to concurrency the measurement won't be exact, as pre-emption could occur between measurement and action (eg discussed in this video [Google I/O 2012 - Go Concurrency Patterns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs)). I'll be using this for flow control between producers and consumers ie once I've passed through a high watermark, changing some behaviour until I pass back through a low watermark.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len

> **func len(v Type) int**
> The len built-in function returns the length of v, according to its type:
>
> - Array: the number of elements in v.
> - Pointer to array: the number of elements in *v (even if v is nil).
> - Slice, or map: the number of elements in v; if v is nil, len(v) is zero.
> - String: the number of bytes in v.
> - Channel: the number of elements queued (unread) in the channel buffer; if v is nil, len(v) is zero.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        c := make(chan int, 100)
        for i := 0; i < 34; i++ {
                c <- 0
        }
        fmt.Println(len(c))
}
```

will output:

```
34
```

Comment: Thanks Artem. That's an un-expected use of len - I would have expected it to return the capacity of a channel, not the number of elements in it! Good to know, thanks again.

Comment: If you would have wanted the capacity, then the built in function `cap` would do it.

Comment: What I find interesting here is that if the channel is made without a capacity(`c := make(chan int)`) you cannot get it's length. I haven't found a reason for this. Yes, it's capacity returns as 0 as well

Comment: I feel weird that when it's unbuffered, I can't get its length. And when using goroutines, it kinda messes up.

Comment: @Brettski and Berkant, If the channel is unbuffered (capacity=0), the length will always be zero. The sender blocks until the receiver has received the value. https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels

Comment: @Brettski I don't follow. You *can* get the length of an unbuffered channel - at least in the latest version of go you can: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pScaAbZPgPg)

Comment: It will always return zero (I tried to find an example, but I haven't been working with go for almost 4 months)

Comment: len() of an unbuffered channel always returns zero because it is always zero (ie it has _no_ buffer). Send/recv are synchronous with each other and the value is copied from sender to receiver directly (effectively; I’m not sure if all interim copies are elided)

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of a buffered channel that is sending in a go routine:

```golang
    done := make(chan bool)
    ch1 := make(chan string, 3)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            ch1 <- "hello"
        }
        done <- true
    }()

    <-done
    fmt.Println(len(ch1))
```