# How does the behavior of a buffered channel differ from my expectations in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, channel

I am trying to understand how a buffered channel works and wrote a code snippet for it

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func squares(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        num := <-c
        fmt.Println(num * num)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    
        go squares(c)

    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4 // blocks here

    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

As per how I expected the program to behave, the main goroutine starts and continues till c<-4, which at that point gets blocked and the control goes to square goroutine (as the buffer capacity is 3). The loop in the squares goroutine continues till 4th iteration at which point the channel is empty. A read operation on an empty channel is blocking and so the control goes back to main goroutine. At that point the write operation to the channel (c<-4) gets executed, we print "main() stopped" and the program ends.

Meaning I expected the output to be,

```
main() started
1
4
9
main() stopped
```

But I get an output,

```
main() started
1
4
9
16
main() stopped
```

How? Am I missing something about how exactly channels work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003749/number-of-elements-in-a-channel) could help you out

Comment: you should loop through channel values like like so: 
`for value := range channel {
    // do stuff
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how channels work.

Goroutines run concurrently. That means when a goroutine sends to a buffered channel, another goroutine waiting to receive from that channel can receive it immediately. It does not wait for the channel to fill up.

As for the ending of the program, when you send the last number to the channel, there is no guarantee that the goroutine will pick it up and print the output before the program ends, because you are not waiting for the goroutine to complete. So, by luck, it runs and prints the output. There will be other executions where this does not happen, and the program terminates before the goroutine can print the output.

Comment: Ok, so once we start writing to the channel, it will start printing the data in the squares goroutine concurrently and doesn't wait for the channel to fill up. 

But the last write operation on channel (c <- 4), shouldn't that be blocking as we are trying to write to a channel buffered to its full capacity? In that case, we should always print the 2nd answer which I eventually got. Why should there be ambiguity of which goroutine finishes first?

Comment: If the goroutine reads from the channel before it is full, the last write will not block, because the channel is not full.

Comment: Ok. So nothing's guaranteed. We might keep on writing to the channel and it may just print the data immediately but before it does so for all the values, the main() finishes the execution and we don't print all the values or vice versa or we may have some other executions where something else happens.

Comment: There are guarantees, and there are ways to use those to enforce behavior. What is not guaranteed is the execution order of concurrent functions. With a buffered channel, the fact that a send succeeded doesn't mean that it is received on the receiving end. However, this is guaranteed for an unbuffered channel. But then, it is not guaranteed that the printf will run before the program terminates.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I am able to comprehend the code now and understand why it behaved the way it did. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is a race between `main()` and the goroutine after the goroutine receives the first value. Any execution order between `main()` and the goroutine is possible after that synchronization point.

Sprinkle in some calls to time.Sleep to observe the race. If the goroutine sleeps after receive, then it's probable that `main()` wins the race and exits before any squares are printed.

```
func squares(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        num := <-c
        time.Sleep(100)
        fmt.Println(num * num)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/x-3wiWwFQGj

If `main()` sleeps after the last send, then it's probable that the  goroutine wins the race and prints the four squares.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan int, 3)

    go squares(c)

    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4 

    time.Sleep(100)
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/HIpRKdbA5qa

These are just two possible outputs from the program.  The goroutine can print a value after the `main() stopped` is printed and before main exits.  The goroutine can print between zero and four values.

I say "probable" above because the sleeps do not ensure the outcome described.